# How to stage deleted files inside a deleted folder

Tags: git, git-rm

I'm trying to stage individual files for delete, but git (v1.9.1) refuses to stage them because the folder where they used to reside has already been deleted.

I cannot use `git add -u` because it will stage *all* modified and deleted files. If I do

`git add -u /path/to/deleted/folder/afile`

or

`git rm /path/to/deleted/folder/afile`

I get:

> fatal: Could not switch to '/path/to/deleted/folder/': No such file or
>   directory

Which is because `/path/to/deleted/folder/` no longer exists.

I cannot understand why git needs to switch to a directory when being told to stage deleted files and having to manually recreate each deleted folder just to let git know, that yes, the file really is gone seems insane.

Is there a way of forcing git to stage a deleted file without requiring the path to exist?

Comment: `git rm --cached /path/to/deleted/folder/afile` does exactly what you want.  Here's the description from the help: "--cached
Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone."

Comment: @Wolf yes, that's what I thought too, but it still returns an error about the missing folder and refuses to stage the deleted file.

Comment: Are you able to install a newer version of git?  You could also try adding the path separator and see if that helps `git rm -- /path/to/deleted/folder/afile`.  That worked as expected locally, but I'm using 2.5.

Comment: I am also using 2.5 and succeeding when I try to stage the deletion.

Comment: Thanks guys - I'll upgrade and see if that fixes it.

Comment: In older version of git (1.8.3.1) using `git rm -rf path/to/folder` stagged the deleted folder files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all credit to Wolf and ROMANARMY, upgrading to 2.5 allows `git rm` to succeed.

Just in case anyone else cares, here's how I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 from the default git to 2.5:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install git

$ git --version
git version 2.5.0
```